# Laravel 5.6 + SAML2

Tags: php, laravel, saml, saml-2.0

I want to integrate SAML2 in Laravel application.
I don't want to use the third party IDP and SP.

I simply want to use Laravel authentication system + SAML2.

Anyone idea about it?
Please share any reference link or suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm interested in this too as I am looking to integrate laravel 5.6 with SAML to talk to our ADFS. I am confused as everything points to `aacotroneo/laravel-saml2` as the library to use but yet I can't get it installed due to `mcrypt is missing from your system` errors, which apparently is now deprecated in Laravel 5.6.  I just seem to be going round in circles.

Comment: There's a plan already to upgrade the project to use v3.0.0 of OneLogin, see: https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2/issues/122. The upgrade was temporarily effected in this branch: https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2/tree/remove_mcrypt based on this discussion: https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2/issues/122#issuecomment-369262809 I am also following until it's changed

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

Make these changes to `composer.json`:

```
{

    "require": {
        "aacotroneo/laravel-saml2": "dev-remove_mcrypt",
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/thomhickey/laravel-saml2"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
 }
```

Then run: `composer update`

If you need more info head over to: https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2/issues/122

Answer (score 0):

It's not good idea to reinvent the wheel. I recommend you should use

https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2

package.

In case you need, this SO answer might be helpful

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/62331871/8621306