# Azure Active Directory SSO with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, azure, active-directory, single-sign-on

I'm doing sso with azure active directory. I have done the setup on azure and go the keys. I'm using metrogistics/laravel-azure-ad-oauth (https://packagist.org/packages/metrogistics/laravel-azure-ad-oauth) package on laravel to do this. However, when I hit the url http://localhost:8000/login/microsoft , I got redirected to microsoft login page and given an error message.

[image]

I have added following configurations to env file and did whatever package has demanded.

AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (this is application id from azure)
AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET=XXXXXXXXX (created a new key on azure)

It's been two days I'm searching the internet but could not find a solution. What is it I'm missing here?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try to login or this pops up right away? Where did you register the app? The Azure AD blade in the Azure portal (portal.azure.com)?

Comment: This pops up when I try to login (after giving the credentials). Yes, I registered the app in Azure AD blade in azure portal

Comment: Is your app a multi-tenant app? I see you have set the authority as the "common" authority that allows users from any AAD tenant to login.

Comment: My actual app is multi-tenant. But I have created a sample app to test simplest flow. If this works, I will move to multi-tenant.

Answer (score 18):

For those people who are still struggling to `Azure Active Directory` SSO in `Laravel`. And if you are willing to use SAML.
Here is the repo they can use.

https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2

*It's very simple to use provided you have done SSO setup correctly on Azure portal.*

It is two step process

### Step 1- Setup SSO project on Azure Portal

---

**a)** Go to `Azure Active Directory` and then `Enterprise Application`

**b)** Add New Application and choose `Non-gallery Application`

**c)** Click `Set up single sign on` and then click on `SAML` Box

**d)** Edit the `basic SAML configuration` and add the following

> **Identifier (Entity ID)** - https://my-laravel-website.com/saml2/aad/metadata
>
> **Reply URL (Assertion Consumer Service URL)** -
> https://my-laravel-website.com/saml2/aad/acs

*(From where these urls are coming, I will explain in **Step 2**. For now just save it.)*

**e)** Download `Federation Metadata XML` from `SAML Signing Certificate` section, on your system

**f)** Next assign users to your current SAML SSO project.

***Note- If there is no user exist in your account. Then you need to create one and assign some role(it's necessary)*.**

*This is the tutorial to setup step 1
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xn_8Fm7S7y8*

.

### Step 2- Install and configure Laravel SAML 2 package in your Project

---

**a)** run `composer require aacotroneo/laravel-saml2`

**b)** run `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Aacotroneo\Saml2\Saml2ServiceProvider"`

**c)** config/saml2_settings.php

```
<?php

return $settings = array(

    /**
     * Array of IDP prefixes to be configured e.g. 'idpNames' => ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'],
     * Separate routes will be automatically registered for each IDP specified with IDP name as prefix
     * Separate config file saml2/<idpName>_idp_settings.php should be added & configured accordingly
     */
    'idpNames' => ['aad'],

    /**
     * If 'useRoutes' is set to true, the package defines five new routes for reach entry in idpNames:
     *
     *    Method | URI                                | Name
     *    -------|------------------------------------|------------------
     *    POST   | {routesPrefix}/{idpName}/acs       | saml_acs
     *    GET    | {routesPrefix}/{idpName}/login     | saml_login
     *    GET    | {routesPrefix}/{idpName}/logout    | saml_logout
     *    GET    | {routesPrefix}/{idpName}/metadata  | saml_metadata
     *    GET    | {routesPrefix}/{idpName}/sls       | saml_sls
     */
    'useRoutes' => true,

    /**
     * Optional, leave empty if you want the defined routes to be top level, i.e. "/{idpName}/*"
     */
    'routesPrefix' => 'saml2',

    /**
     * which middleware group to use for the saml routes
     * Laravel 5.2 will need a group which includes StartSession
     */
    'routesMiddleware' => ['saml'],

    /**
     * Indicates how the parameters will be
     * retrieved from the sls request for signature validation
     */
    'retrieveParametersFromServer' => false,

    /**
     * Where to redirect after logout
     */
    'logoutRoute' => '/login',

    /**
     * Where to redirect after login if no other option was provided
     */
    'loginRoute' => '/dashboard',

    /**
     * Where to redirect after login if no other option was provided
     */
    'errorRoute' => '/login',

    // If 'proxyVars' is True, then the Saml lib will trust proxy headers
    // e.g X-Forwarded-Proto / HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO. This is useful if
    // your application is running behind a load balancer which terminates
    // SSL.
    'proxyVars' => true,

    /**
     * (Optional) Which class implements the route functions.
     * If commented out, defaults to this lib's controller (Aacotroneo\Saml2\Http\Controllers\Saml2Controller).
     * If you need to extend Saml2Controller (e.g. to override the `login()` function to pass
     * a `$returnTo` argument), this value allows you to pass your own controller, and have
     * it used in the routes definition.
     */
     'saml2_controller' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\SAML2LoginController',
);
```

*Note* - Part **d)** of **Step 1** is coming from the following

[image]

**d)** Create a new file `config/saml2/aad_idp_settings.php` and copy the contents of `config/saml2/test_idp_settings.php` into it. Change `$this_idp_env_id` in `aad_idp_settings.php` to **'AAD'**. So the final `aad_idp_settings.php` will look like the following.

```
<?php

// If you choose to use ENV vars to define these values, give this IdP its own env var names
// so you can define different values for each IdP, all starting with 'SAML2_'.$this_idp_env_id
$this_idp_env_id = 'AAD';

//This is variable is for simplesaml example only.
// For real IdP, you must set the url values in the 'idp' config to conform to the IdP's real urls.
$idp_host = env('SAML2_'.$this_idp_env_id.'_IDP_HOST', 'http://localhost:8000/simplesaml');

return $settings = array(

    /*****
     * One Login Settings
     */

    // If 'strict' is True, then the PHP Toolkit will reject unsigned
    // or unencrypted messages if it expects them signed or encrypted
    // Also will reject the messages if not strictly follow the SAML
    // standard: Destination, NameId, Conditions ... are validated too.
    'strict' => true, //@todo: make this depend on laravel config

    // Enable debug mode (to print errors)
    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    // Service Provider Data that we are deploying
    'sp' => array(

        // Specifies constraints on the name identifier to be used to
        // represent the requested subject.
        // Take a look on lib/Saml2/Constants.php to see the NameIdFormat supported
        'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent',

        // Usually x509cert and privateKey of the SP are provided by files placed at
        // the certs folder. But we can also provide them with the following parameters
        'x509cert' => env('SAML2_'.$this_idp_env_id.'_SP_x509',''),
        'privateKey' => env('SAML2_'.$this_idp_env_id.'_SP_PRIVATEKEY',''),

        // Identifier (URI) of the SP entity.
        // Leave blank to use the '{idpName}_metadata' route, e.g. 'test_metadata'.
        'entityId' => env('SAML2_'.$this_idp_env_id.'_SP_ENTITYID',''),

        // Specifies info about where and how the <AuthnResponse> message MUST be
        // returned to the requester, in this case our SP.
        'assertionConsumerService' => array(
            // URL Location where the <Response> from the IdP will be returned,
            // using HTTP-POST binding.
            // Leave blank to use the '{idpName}_acs' route, e.g. 'test_acs'
            'url' => '',
        ),
        // Specifies info about where and how the <Logout Response> message MUST be
        // returned to the requester, in this case our SP.
        // Remove this part to not include any URL Location in the metadata.
        'singleLogoutService' => array(
            // URL Location where the <Response> from the IdP will be returned,
            // using HTTP-Redirect binding.
            // Leave blank to use the '{idpName}_sls' route, e.g. 'test_sls'
            'url' => '',
        ),
    ),

    // Identity Provider Data that we want connect with our SP
    'idp' => array(
        // Identifier of the IdP entity  (must be a URI)
        'entityId' => env('SAML2_'.$this_idp_env_id.'_IDP_ENTITYID', $idp_host . '/saml2/idp/metadata.php'),
        // SSO endpoint info of the IdP. (Authentication Request protocol)
        'singleSignOnService' => array(
            // URL Target of the IdP where the SP will send the Authentication Request Message,
            // using HTTP-Redirect binding.
            'url' => env('SAML2_'.$this_idp_env_id.'_IDP_SSO_URL', $idp_host . '/saml2/idp/SSOService.php'),
        ),
        // SLO endpoint info of the IdP.
        'singleLogoutService' => array(
            // URL Location of the IdP where the SP will send the SLO Request,
            // using HTTP-Redirect binding.
            'url' => env('SAML2_'.$this_idp_env_id.'_IDP_SL_URL', $idp_host . '/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php'),
        ),
        // Public x509 certificate of the IdP
        'x509cert' => env('SAML2_'.$this_idp_env_id.'_IDP_x509', 'MIID/TCCAuWgAwIBAgIJAI4R3WyjjmB1MA0GCS'),
        /*
         *  Instead of use the whole x509cert you can use a fingerprint
         *  (openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -in "idp.crt" to generate it)
         */
        // 'certFingerprint' => '',
    ),



    /***
     *
     *  OneLogin advanced settings
     *
     *
     */
    // Security settings
    'security' => array(

        /** signatures and encryptions offered */

        // Indicates that the nameID of the <samlp:logoutRequest> sent by this SP
        // will be encrypted.
        'nameIdEncrypted' => false,

        // Indicates whether the <samlp:AuthnRequest> messages sent by this SP
        // will be signed.              [The Metadata of the SP will offer this info]
        'authnRequestsSigned' => false,

        // Indicates whether the <samlp:logoutRequest> messages sent by this SP
        // will be signed.
        'logoutRequestSigned' => false,

        // Indicates whether the <samlp:logoutResponse> messages sent by this SP
        // will be signed.
        'logoutResponseSigned' => false,

        /* Sign the Metadata
         False || True (use sp certs) || array (
                                                    keyFileName => 'metadata.key',
                                                    certFileName => 'metadata.crt'
                                                )
        */
        'signMetadata' => false,


        /** signatures and encryptions required **/

        // Indicates a requirement for the <samlp:Response>, <samlp:LogoutRequest> and
        // <samlp:LogoutResponse> elements received by this SP to be signed.
        'wantMessagesSigned' => false,

        // Indicates a requirement for the <saml:Assertion> elements received by
        // this SP to be signed.        [The Metadata of the SP will offer this info]
        'wantAssertionsSigned' => false,

        // Indicates a requirement for the NameID received by
        // this SP to be encrypted.
        'wantNameIdEncrypted' => false,

        // Authentication context.
        // Set to false and no AuthContext will be sent in the AuthNRequest,
        // Set true or don't present thi parameter and you will get an AuthContext 'exact' 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport'
        // Set an array with the possible auth context values: array ('urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:X509'),
        'requestedAuthnContext' => true,
    ),

    // Contact information template, it is recommended to suply a technical and support contacts
    'contactPerson' => array(
        'technical' => array(
            'givenName' => 'name',
            'emailAddress' => 'no@reply.com'
        ),
        'support' => array(
            'givenName' => 'Support',
            'emailAddress' => 'no@reply.com'
        ),
    ),

    // Organization information template, the info in en_US lang is recomended, add more if required
    'organization' => array(
        'en-US' => array(
            'name' => 'Name',
            'displayname' => 'Display Name',
            'url' => 'http://url'
        ),
    ),

/* Interoperable SAML 2.0 Web Browser SSO Profile [saml2int]   http://saml2int.org/profile/current

   'authnRequestsSigned' => false,    // SP SHOULD NOT sign the <samlp:AuthnRequest>,
                                      // MUST NOT assume that the IdP validates the sign
   'wantAssertionsSigned' => true,
   'wantAssertionsEncrypted' => true, // MUST be enabled if SSL/HTTPs is disabled
   'wantNameIdEncrypted' => false,
*/

);
```

**e)** Now we need to put following ENV vars

```
SAML2_AAD_IDP_ENTITYID=
SAML2_AAD_IDP_SSO_URL=
SAML2_AAD_IDP_SL_URL=
SAML2_AAD_IDP_x509=
```

The value of first 3 env vars will be coming from here.

[image]

The last Env var will come from following

[image]

[image]

**f)** run `php artisan make:provider SAML2ServiceProvider`. This will create a file in `app/Providers/SAML2ServiceProvider.php`.

In the **boot** method paste the following snippet

```
Event::listen('Aacotroneo\Saml2\Events\Saml2LoginEvent', function (Saml2LoginEvent $event) {
            $messageId = $event->getSaml2Auth()->getLastMessageId();
            // Add your own code preventing reuse of a $messageId to stop replay attacks

            $user = $event->getSaml2User();
            $userData = [
                'id' => $user->getUserId(),
                'attributes' => $user->getAttributes(),
                'assertion' => $user->getRawSamlAssertion()
            ];

            $inputs = [
                'sso_user_id'  => $user->getUserId(),
                'username'     => self::getValue($user->getAttribute('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name')),
                'email'        => self::getValue($user->getAttribute('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name')),
                'first_name'   => self::getValue($user->getAttribute('http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname')),
                'last_name'    => self::getValue($user->getAttribute('http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname')),
                'password'     => Hash::make('anything'),
             ];

            $user = User::where('sso_user_id', $inputs['sso_user_id'])->where('email', $inputs['email'])->first();
            if(!$user){
                $res = PortalUser::store($inputs);
                if($res['status'] == 'success'){
                    $user  = $res['data'];
                    Auth::guard('web')->login($user);
                }else{
                    Log::info('SAML USER Error '.$res['messages']);
                }
            }else{
                Auth::guard('web')->login($user);
            }

        });
```

and finally register this provider in **providers** array of `config/app.php`.

### .
Test the SAML AAD SSO

---

Go to `https://[your-site-url]/saml2/aad/login`

Comment: Do you miss out on step 1's e?

Comment: How to approach this if I want to be able to connect to multiple Azure tenants?

Comment: Looks like aacotroneo/laravel-saml2 is older and no active, may not support the latest Laravel versions.