# How to Authenticate the data from Microsoft Azure AD using Laravel and redirect it to Home?

Tags: php, laravel, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I'm trying to authenticate Microsoft Azure AD with my laravel web app. Currently I'm referring [Azure Active Directory SSO with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289010/azure-active-directory-sso-with-laravel). I managed to retrieve the data from the microsoft azure ad but the problem is it doesn't redirect to /home view instead it redirect to login view.

I have one idea which is to link the email from Microsoft and email from the model so that it can directly go to home page. But i dont know how to pass the Microsoft data (from provider) to controller. The code(in Provider) below is what I did so far.

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Aacotroneo\Saml2\Events\Saml2LoginEvent;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class SAML2ServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
    public const HOME = '/home';
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        Event::listen('Aacotroneo\Saml2\Events\Saml2LoginEvent', function (Saml2LoginEvent $event) {

            // dd($event);
            $messageId = $event->getSaml2Auth()->getLastMessageId();
            // Add your own code preventing reuse of a $messageId to stop replay attacks

            $user = $event->getSaml2User();
            $userData = [
                'id' => $user->getUserId(),
                'attributes' => $user->getAttributes(),
                'assertion' => $user->getRawSamlAssertion()
            ];

            //dd($userData);
            $inputs = [
                'sso_user_id'  => $user->getUserId(),
                'username'     => $user->getAttribute('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name'),
                'email'        => $user->getAttribute('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress'),
                'first_name'   => $user->getAttribute('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname'),
                'last_name'    => $user->getAttribute('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname'),
                'password'     => Hash::make('anything'),
             ];

            //  dd($inputs);

            // $user = User::where('sso_user_id', $inputs['sso_user_id'])->where('email', $inputs['email'])->first();
            // if(!$user){
            //     $res = PortalUser::store($inputs);
            //     if($res['status'] == 'success'){
            //         $user  = $res['data'];
            //         Auth::guard('web')->login($user);
            //     }else{
            //         Log::info('SAML USER Error '.$res['messages']);
            //     }
            // }else{
                Auth::guard('web')->login($user);
            // }

        });
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me on this issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague help me on this and below are the solution where he link the Microsoft email with email from the model

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Aacotroneo\Saml2\Events\Saml2LoginEvent;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class SAML2ServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    public const HOME = '/home';

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Event::listen('Aacotroneo\Saml2\Events\Saml2LoginEvent', function (Saml2LoginEvent $event) {

            // dd($event);
            // $messageId = $event->getSaml2Auth()->getLastMessageId();
            // Add your own code preventing reuse of a $messageId to stop replay attacks

            $user = $event->getSaml2User();
            // $userData = [
            //     'id' => $user->getUserId(),
            //     'attributes' => $user->getAttributes(),
            //     'assertion' => $user->getRawSamlAssertion()
            // ];

            // dd($userData);
            $inputs = [
                'sso_user_id'  => $user->getUserId(),
                'username'     => $user->getAttribute('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name'),
                'email'        => $user->getAttribute('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress'),
                'first_name'   => $user->getAttribute('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname'),
                'last_name'    => $user->getAttribute('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname'),
                'password'     => Hash::make('anything'),
             ];

            //  dd($inputs['email'][0]);



            $user = User::where('email', $inputs['email'][0])->first();
            // dd($user->id);

            if(!$user){
               return view ('404');
            }else{
                Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
                session()->regenerate();
            }

        });
    }
}
```