# Laravel - How to global logout using Azure AD SLO?

Tags: php, laravel, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have successfully did [How to Authenticate the data from Microsoft Azure AD using Laravel and redirect it to Home?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64155625/how-to-authenticate-the-data-from-microsoft-azure-ad-using-laravel-and-redirect/64526836#64526836) and then I would like to global logout from Laravel and Microsoft. I had refer to https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2 but it did not work. I have also tried to do HTTP Client.

The only problem is I could not logout from Microsoft where I had to post SAMLRequest and RelayState as well which I could not find during debugging.

Other Option: referring to [Azure Active Directory SSO with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289010/azure-active-directory-sso-with-laravel). I can point the Http::post to https:{domain}/saml/logout. but it did not work.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Aacotroneo\Saml2\Saml2Auth;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function logout( )
    {

        //Saml2Auth::logout();

        Http::post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/wsfederation?wa=wsignout1.0');

        //other option
        Http::post('https://newsaml.test/saml/logout');

        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');

    }
}
```

Comment: what are you getting as response for `Http::post()` any errors?

Comment: Hi @bhucho, I get status code 200 which is a success right ? But it still did not logout from the Microsoft