# Laravel and Azure ad SSO

Tags: php, laravel, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml

I'm trying to implement Azure SAML SSO in Laravel (I'm using laravel 8)
I followed the answer on another question posted here in stackoverflow ([Azure Active Directory SSO with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289010/azure-active-directory-sso-with-laravel)).
When I go to the page of login the server gives me a 404 error, and from the logs I read this:

Saml2 error_detail {"error":"Invalid issuer in the Assertion/Response (expected 'https://{my_project_url}/saml2/aad/metadata', got 'https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/')"}

I'm stuck and there is lack of documentation about this laravel package.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you post the redacted configuration info from the Azure AD side? Most likely you've entered the information incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings were incorrect as mentioned in the comment below the question

Comment: To complete your answer, Please post the correct settings here.