# Laravel and AZURE SSO with SAML using aacotroneo/laravel-saml2 package

Tags: php, laravel, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml

I'm trying to implement SAML authentication against Azure AD in my Laravel application using aacotroneo/laravel-saml2 package.
I configured the IDP settings and the microsoft login page appears correctly as it should be.
The problem is that I'm not able to take user informations from Azure.
I followed the instructions found in the answer of this question [Azure Active Directory SSO with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289010/azure-active-directory-sso-with-laravel)
I changed the code inside the file app/Providers/SAML2ServiceProvider.php adding these lines:

```php
public function boot()
    {
        Event::listen('Aacotroneo\Saml2\Events\Saml2LogoutEvent', function ($event) {
            if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
                session_start();
            }
            unset($_SESSION["id"]);
            session_destroy();
        });

        Event::listen('Aacotroneo\Saml2\Events\Saml2LoginEvent', function (Saml2LoginEvent $event) {
            $messageId = $event->getSaml2Auth()->getLastMessageId();
            // Add your own code preventing reuse of a $messageId to stop replay attacks
            if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
                session_start();
            }
            $user = $event->getSaml2User();
            Log::info("COOKIE_SAML ACTIVATED");
            $_COOKIE["COOKIE_SAML"] = 1;

            $userData = [
                'id' => $user->getUserId(),
                'attributes' => $user->getAttributes(),
                'assertion' => $user->getRawSamlAssertion()
            ];

            Log::info(json_encode($userData));

            $inputs = [
                'sso_user_id'  => self::getValue($user->getUserId()),
                // 'username'     => $user->getAttribute('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name'),
                'email'        => self::getValue($user->getAttribute('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name')),
                'first_name'   => self::getValue($user->getAttribute('http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname')),
                'last_name'    => self::getValue($user->getAttribute('http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname')),
            ];

            $user = UserAdecco::where('sso_user_id', $inputs['sso_user_id'])->where('email', $inputs['email'])->first();
            if (!$user) {
                $res = UserAdecco::store($inputs);
                if ($res['status'] == 'success') {
                    $user  = $res['data'];
                    $_SESSION["id"] = $user->id;
                    // Auth::guard('web')->login($user);
                } else {
                    Log::info('SAML USER Error ' . $res['messages']);
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["id"] = $user->id;
                // Auth::guard('web')->login($user);
            }
        });
    }
```

But it seems that this code is not executed at all. The result is that when I login nothing happens and the user is not logged inside the Laravel application.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the service provider needs to be registered inside config/app.php to work.

Comment: I followed the steps too but my app doesn't seem to redirect to the Microsoft login screen. Is there a specific route that I am to set, which would redirect users to the Microsoft login screen?

Thanks